# Crash in CFNetwork on iOS 11

Tags: crash, ios11, cfnetwork

Facing the following crash recently on iOS11.  Any known crash in iOS11  ?

```
Thread 13 crashed:

#  1  0x0000000185e5da70 in TubeManager::_onqueue_newTubeReady(Tube*, CFStreamError) + 992 (CFNetwork + 0x00000000000d6a70) 0x0000000000000000
#  2  0x0000000185e5da70 in TubeManager::_onqueue_newTubeReady(Tube*, CFStreamError) + 992 (CFNetwork + 0x00000000000d6a70) 0x0000000000000000
#  3  0x0000000185e5d438 in invocation function for block in TubeManager::requestNewTube(BaseAwaitingTube*, void (Tube*) block_pointer) + 28 (CFNetwork + 0x00000000000d6438) 0x000000016fe2e5e0
#  4  0x0000000185e8e2f4 in Tube::_onqueue_invokeCB(CFStreamError) + 160 (CFNetwork + 0x00000000001072f4) 0x000000016fe2e600
#  5  0x0000000185e8d04c in Tube::_onqueue_errorHandler(CFStreamError) + 148 (CFNetwork + 0x000000000010604c) 0x000000016fe2e630
#  6  0x0000000185e8e978 in Tube::connectionEstablished(CFStreamError) + 408 (CFNetwork + 0x0000000000107978) 0x000000016fe2e660
#  7  0x0000000185182a4c in _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 16 (libdispatch.dylib + 0x0000000000001a4c) 0x000000016fe2e6a0
#  8  0x0000000185182a0c in _dispatch_client_callout + 8 (libdispatch.dylib + 0x0000000000001a0c) 0x000000016fe2e6c0
#  9  0x000000018518c964 in _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 520 (libdispatch.dylib + 0x000000000000b964) 0x000000016fe2e6e0
# 10  0x000000018518d2f4 in _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 332 (libdispatch.dylib + 0x000000000000c2f4) 0x000000016fe2e780
# 11  0x000000018518c81c in _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 192 (libdispatch.dylib + 0x000000000000b81c) 0x000000016fe2e810
# 12  0x000000018518d2f4 in _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 332 (libdispatch.dylib + 0x000000000000c2f4) 0x000000016fe2e8b0
# 13  0x000000018518dd18 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 396 (libdispatch.dylib + 0x000000000000cd18) 0x000000016fe2e940
# 14  0x0000000185196034 in _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 636 (libdispatch.dylib + 0x0000000000015034) 0x000000016fe2e9c0
# 15  0x000000018542af14 in _pthread_wqthread + 924 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 0x0000000000000f14) 0x000000016fe2ea40
# 16  0x000000018542ab64 in pthread_workqueue_addthreads_np + 120 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 0x0000000000000b64) 0x000000016fe2eae0
```

Comment: I have a same/similar crash on macOS 10.12.6

Comment: Please, read the 7 Nov post.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110493